# Can't execute a cron job

Tags: python, cron

I am creating a `cron job` to execute a `python` script

`hello.py`

```
a = 'a cron job was executed here'
text_file = open('output_hello.txt', 'w')
text_file.write(a)
text_file.close()
```

Works fine if I execute via terminal, I am on ubuntu 15.10.

My `cron job` file is:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/rohit/hello.py
(excluding the #)
```

I am a root user and creating the job in `/var/spool/cron`

The issue is that it is not executing the script. I don't know why.

Comment: I think you're being downvoted because your question is ugly.  Take a look at the SO [markdown tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply modify the crontab, you run the command:

```
crontab -e
```

and edit from there. Execute the above command using `sudo` if you want it to run as root.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your paths are correct, your script may not have the right environment or it may not be executable. Ensure your script starts with:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

And also that you then give execute permission to that script:

`chmod a+x hello.py`

Ensure you use `crontab -e` and if you have any doubts about your syntax, you can find more info here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto